# What are the drawbacks of putting product price and product discount in my products table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database table called `products` which has the following columns:

```
Table: Products
Columns: id, name, price, discount
```

I read that it is not a bad idea to have the `price` and `discount` in separate tables, but I was wondering if there are any huge drawbacks to keeping them in the `products` table. Also, if I opt in for the extra tables, do I need `prices` table and `discounts` table, or should I have both the price and discount in the same table?

Comment: This question runs the danger of getting only opinions, which is outside the scope of SO. That being said: Either of the three options you propose are suitable for different situations. If you want to keep old prices/discounts it is practical to use a separate table, if you don't care about old prices you can overwrite them in the products table. Another reason could be that you want to vary prices per country, type of client, etc.

Comment: If price and discount never changed, keeping the together could be a good idea. However, they probably will change. And... when they do, they'll change at different times, and the change is responsibility of different people. A real-world commerce model typically divides this data in three tables: `product`, `product_price`, `promotion`.